# Como cambiar el color de una celda de un datagrid c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

mi duda es saber como puedo cambiar el color de una celda por código c#, y lo quiero hacer recorriendo los elementos de mi datagrid de wpf. Gracias por su ayuda.

Probe con las siguientes lineas de comandos ya que quiero pintar solo una parte de las celdas del datagrid

```
for (int i = 1; i < dgMatriz.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                firstRow = dgMatriz.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dgMatriz.Items[i]) as DataGridRow;
                firstColumnInFirstRow = dgMatriz.Columns[j].GetCellContent(firstRow) as DataGridCell;
                firstColumnInFirstRow.Background = Brushes.Red;

            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí solo quiero que se pinten solo esas celdas

Comment: Explicate mas, que condicion debe cumplir esa celda para cambiar de color y pon lo q has intentado

Comment: listo, en mi datagrid muestro una matriz 4x4 y solo quiero colorear el triangulo superior, y para ello quiero tambien recorrer el datagrid,

Comment: A ver, seria bueno que nos ilustraras con una imagen lo q intentas hacer, porque asi en palabras es dificil ubicarnos

Comment: ya actualizo el comentario principal